# how to use php session start function?

Tags: php, session

hi to all i have a question. i have declare session_start() in my header file. and in the other file m accessing the user information from the following way. first in my log-in file m assigning the session variable a value that is the user log-information. like `$_SESSION['userlogin']=$name;` and in my other file m accessing the user log-in in the following way `$user = $_SESSION['userlogin'] ;`and storing into the database.
but when m going to store the information i got the following error.
"undefined index userlogin". i try hard to search out the solution but didn't find anyone. plz help me so that i complete task at the time

Answer (score 0):

You only have to declare session_start(); once per page I think. I normally only start_session() if I'm going to be using it.

Comment: the header file that i m using is included in each file and the header file is loaded on every new action.

Comment: Just do a simple test. Remove the header file and do session_start(); in the page you setting the username in session and do session_start(); again in the page where you are accessing. See if it makes a difference.

Comment: it work accurately. but i want to get a rid of from writing the session_start() again and on every file

Comment: I understand that for ease of maintainence. Perhaps some PHP gurus can explain why you can't include session_start() in a header file. My guess is it's based on the scope of the page. Now get back to your project and get on with it and check this question later. You can always fix it later :)

Comment: you mean the scope of session_start() is limited on the page on which it is declared?????

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have an `session_start();` in both files above the code where you handling the sessions